# How do I SSH into Ubuntu on VirtualBox?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox-networking

How do I SSH into Ubuntu from an outside network? It's running in VirtualBox and the network adapter has to remain NAT. I can't seem to figure out how to set it up. Are there any ways to directly SSH into the VirtualBox session?

Answer (score 2):

When the VM networking is based on NAT, you need to use port forwarding to remotely access the VM (here named ubuntu).

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "ubuntu" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,2222,,22"
```

Then you'll be able to access the VM by connecting to the host on port 2222, eg:

```
ssh -p 2222 user@host
```